# How to show progress bar while attaching files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, progress-bar

I am attaching file for mail through C#. I am using below code:

```
  Attachment data = new Attachment(fileName);
  mailMsg.Attachments.Add(data);
```

I want to show a progress bar while attaching file. How can I do this?

Comment: How can attaching a file take more than a millisecond? What computer are you using?!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the `mailMsg` object has some kind of progress event, you probably can't get the progress for a single attatchment.

However, if you are attatching multiple files, you can report the ratio of files completed to total files as a percentage instead. To do that, add a `ProgressBar` to your window, then update the value of it after each file is done.